# How can i cascade the values below and add them to the top number in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

So i have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
A   B   C               D           Start Time   End Time
1   5’  1st shift       Bathroom A  08:30        09:30
0   2’  1st shift       Bathroom A  09:30        10:30
0   3’  1st shift       Bathroom A  10:30        11:30
1   1’  1st shift       Bathroom B  11:30        12:30
0   2’  1st shift       Bathroom B  12:30        1:30
1   1’  2nd shift       Bathroom D  1:30         2:30
1   4’  2st shift       Bathroom B  2:30         3:30
1   5’  3rd shift       Bathroom B .
0   6’  3rd shift       Bathroom A .
```

What I am trying to do is to aggregate column B based on the 0's that are seen on column A for example like this:

```
A   B   C   D   Start Time   End Time
1   10’ 1st A   08:30        11:30
1   3’  1st B   11:30        1:30
1   1’  2nd b   1:30         2:30 
1   4’  2rd d   2:30         3:30 
1   5’  3rd b
```

So the 10' was calculated because the one's with the 0's cascaded to the one above: (5+2+3 = 10')
the 3' was calculated because (1+2 = 3' etc)

i did cumsum and groupby the sum in python, however, when i do that, it sums up the shift as well the 1st shift becomes 3rd shift, the dates get added etc.

All i want is to just add the time (seen in the dataframe below) and remvove the entire row. just like in the second picture.
can someone please help me, I have been trying to do this for a day now and i still cant figure out what im doing wrongly :(

edit: i was thinking of doing like a rolling sum however, that wont work because the number of 0's will not always be a set number like 3 , 2, or 1.

```
df["C"] = df["A"].cumsum()
df= df.groupby("C").sum()
df.head(10)
```

and my duration gets cascaded properly, but when i do so, the shifts are missing

Comment: You only have one data point for Column E. What should it look like after aggregation? It would help if you included the output of `print(df.to_dict())`

Comment: This is not a dataframe-native answer, so just adding as a comment: if you are familiar with SQL, and just want to get this done, consider using https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/ . With it, what you are asking turns into a pretty straightforward `GROUP BY` query.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try with `groupby` and `agg`:

```
#convert column B to a number
df["B"] = pd.to_numeric(df["B"].str.replace("'",""))

#assign a column called 'group' that cumulates "A" 
#aggregate each column as needed
#drop 'group' after the groupby
result = df.assign(group=df["A"].cumsum()) \
           .groupby("group") \
           .agg({"A": "first", \
                 "B": "sum", \
                 "C": "first", \
                 "D": "first", \
                 "Start Time": "first", \
                 "End Time": "last"}) \
           .reset_index(drop=True)

#apply the required formatting to each column
result["B"] = result["B"].astype(str)+"'"
result["C"] = result["C"].str.replace(" shift", "")
result["D"] = result["D"].str.replace("Bathroom ", "")

>>> result
   A    B    C  D Start Time End Time
0  1  10'  1st  A      08:30    11:30
1  1   3'  1st  B      11:30     1:30
2  1   1'  2nd  D       1:30     2:30
3  1   4'  2st  B       2:30     3:30
4  1  11'  3rd  B       None     None
```

The `df` used:

```
>>> df
   A   B          C           D Start Time End Time
0  1  5'  1st shift  Bathroom A      08:30    09:30
1  0  2'  1st shift  Bathroom A      09:30    10:30
2  0  3'  1st shift  Bathroom A      10:30    11:30
3  1  1'  1st shift  Bathroom B      11:30    12:30
4  0  2'  1st shift  Bathroom B      12:30     1:30
5  1  1'  2nd shift  Bathroom D       1:30     2:30
6  1  4'  2st shift  Bathroom B       2:30     3:30
7  1  5'  3rd shift  Bathroom B       None     None
8  0  6'  3rd shift  Bathroom A       None     None
```

Comment: for the .agg part, do i have to do the A: first , B:sum for all of my columns ?

Comment: The ones you want in your output, yes. And the appropriate aggregation function for each.